# startactivity from onpostexecute() of Asynctask pushes screen even when the application is not in foreground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to launch a activity from onpostexecute of AsyncTask. If application goes background while AsyncTask is being executed, Activity is getting pushed to phone's launcher screen. It is due to the default behaviour of AsyncTask. Is there any way of avoiding this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your activity is going to become no longer visible to the user (home button is pressed, etc) its `onPause()` method will be called.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (myAsyncTask != null) {
        myAsyncTask.Cancel(true); // allow task to be interrupted if in progress
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have a reference to the  AsyncTask in your Activity. If you post your code I'd be better able to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

(if the activity is not in foreground, the the code written inside run() won't execute. in your case the intent)

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(null!=getActivity())
        {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

            });
        }
    }
```

**Edited**- [note: I am using this in fragments. hence its getActivity(). if you have written your AsyncTask within an activity, replace getActivity() with YourActivityName.this]

Comment: Thanks Santhosh.. Will this work even when used from handler? Asynctask returns to handler in my code...

Comment: Also, I'm launching activity from service where I'm facing the same issue. For that, how can I call runOnUiThread method?

Comment: Since for a service there won't be any UI, i don't think you can call runOnUiThread from it. there must be some other way to achieve it. I don't have that much experience on service.

Comment: Ok I ll update you if I get a solution.. thank you soo much for ur time :)